# How to update JSON field in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a settings model in sqlalchemy with flask

```
class Settings(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'setting'
    settings = db.Column(db.JSON(), nullable=False, default={'connections': []})

    def serializable(self):
        return {'settings': self.settings}

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Settings for {self.project} id: {self.id}>'
```

When I try to update `settings` field in the `Settings` table it just does not stick.

```
@settingsBP.route('/delete/<connection_name>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete(connection_name):
    settings = Settings.query.first()
    settings_copy = settings.settings

    for i, v in enumerate(settings_copy['connections']):
        if v['database'] == connection_name:
          del settings_copy['connections'][i]
          break

    settings.settings = settings_copy
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(settings_copy)
```

If I print `settings_copy` it prints correctly. But the `settings.settings` isn't saving any of the changes. I tried modifying the `settings.settings` directly but that did not work.

Comment: Try `db.session.add(settings)` before you commit.

Comment: @YBYu I had tried that previously and it didn't work. I read that it wasn't needed so I removed it to see if it would fix something but alas not.

Comment: The name `settings_copy` is misleading, since it is just another reference to the same `dict`(?) object.